# Loading autocomplete data from remote URL with bootstrap-tagsinput

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tags-input

I want to create a text input with autocomplete, with data populated from my DB.

I've been trying to get bootstrap-tagsinput to work without success. Populating data from a static json file works fine. My server is now returning this (constant result, regardless of the query):

```
[{"text":"Amsterdam","value":0},{"text":"A Coruna","value":1},{"text":"New York","value":2}]
```

When I try the following code, the handler is executed. I see GET petitions on the server's logs as I type in the input box, but the autocomplete feature does not show up.

I tried adding an extra function parameter to `get`, just to popup an alert box when the query was over, but nothing happens. I tried binding the second parameter to `process`, then calling it to "process the data", but obviously that didn't help either.

Any ideas?

(I'm using bootstrap-tagsinput 0.4.2 and jquery 2.1.4).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Tags Input</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-tagsinput.css">
  </head>
  <body>

  <input type="text" value="" data-role="tagsinput" />

  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $('input').tagsinput({
    itemValue: 'value'
    , itemText: 'text'
    , typeahead: {
        source: function(query) {
          return $.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/transactions/categories/' + query);
        }
      }
    , freeInput: false
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is expected match for query property `"text"` or `"value"` ?

Answer (score 0):

The error was somewhere else (server side), but from a normal browser it was producing valid json. It was for ajax requests that was failing.

The code I posted actually works.

Sorry for the noise. Closed now.